# Selected Buttons to Email

Tags: php, html, css

I've set up a multistep form and it's setup to email me the contents via php. The trouble that I'm having is that when I go through the form, at any point that I have more than 1 button to choose from, what I'm being emailed is the last button in the sequence.

P.S. - I'm completely new at this... self teaching.

For Example:

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="Step2">
    <h2 class="fs-title"> Approximately How Many Participants?</h2>
    <input type="" name="count" class="next action-button" value="6-10" />
    <input type="" name="count" class="next action-button" value="10-15" />
    <br>
    <input type="prevnext" name="previous" class="previous prevnext-button" value="Previous" />
</fieldset>
```

PHP:

```
$count = trim(strip_tags($_POST['count']));
```

If I select the 6-10 button, what is emailed to me is the 10-15 OR whatever is last in the sequence.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick responses. Loving this site already and looking forward to learning with you all.

So I'm trying to avoid radio buttons. Essentially, I'm setting up a multistep form where the user clicks a button and it moves to the next field based on the selected button while all of the selected buttons through each field are captured and emailed to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you use the same name attribute for multiple input elements, the last one will be used. You could try name="count[]" then it will be an array. Also the value is always true. Maybe you would to make it a checkbox or radio like this:

```
<fieldset id="Step2">
<h2 class="fs-title"> Approximately How Many Participants?</h2>
<input type="radio" name="count" class="next action-button" value="6-10" />
<input type="radio" name="count" class="next action-button" value="10-15" />
        <br>
<input type="prevnext" name="previous" class="previous prevnext-button" value="Previous" />
</fieldset>
```

Update:

```
<fieldset id="Step">
<input type="input" name="count" value="" id="count">
<button type="button" onclick="changeCount(event);" value="6-10">6-10</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeCount(event);" value="10-15">10-15</button>
<br>
</fieldset>
<script>
function changeCount(event) {
    document.getElementById("count").value = event.target.value;
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6r02ea9c/1/
in the fiddle, i made chose input type input so you can see it change

Comment: Thank you Maarten. So If I wish to have multiple buttons with different values, should name="count[]" be applied to each button? If so, how would I capture the selected button in my PHP?

I'm trying to avoid radios and drop-downs if possible.

Basically, I want to have 4 boxes with different values to choose from... click one and it moves to the next field with another set of boxes to choose from and so on. Essentially, I need the selected boxes reflected in an email.

Comment: I would suggest to use a hidden input field and update the value of the hidden field based on the button pressed. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I'm still figuring it out but I know exactly what you mean. This should do it! :) The fiddle doesn't seem to be updating the field value when a button is clicked but I'm sure I can figure that part out. Thanks a million!!!

Comment: GOT IT! THANKS MAARTEN. Off to the races to get this form complete.

Comment: Good luck with your forms :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both inputs are named `count`

Consider this.

```
$array['count'] = 1;
$array['count'] = 2;
```

Of course the value of `$array['count']` is 2. This is essentially what you are doing with the form.

An appropriate form element for selecting one option from an list is a drop-down.

```
<select name="count">
    <option value="5-10">5-10</option>
    <option value="11-15">11-15</option>
</select>

echo $_POST['count'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Tristan the first thing I would recommend to you is put a type to the inputs.
the name of the button are the same so you should give them a diferent names in order to catch in the action the name of the button and make all you want to do. 
If for some reason you want to have the same name for the buttons you need to make an array e.g

but is something that you dont need to do because the button is only setted when you click on it